# How to relate in the same table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How should the model and table look like where a user with the admin role stores users with a different role? I think that in the User model I need something like this:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'customer_id');
}

public function admin()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'admin_id');
}
```

but I am stuck on what tables should be.

Comment: You can create two different tables users and roles. Assign role id to the user in users table

Answer (score 0):

One admin can have many customers, so it needs to change a bit. And you can use generic `user_id` field as reference key.

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_id');
}

public function admin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: And what should be the tables? I already have an intermediate table for roles.

Comment: if you have roles, it will be different.

Comment: Do I need to create another intermediate table?